# the '-' in command 'virtualenv -p python3 . '

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

When create a virtual env with python, code the command:

```
virtualenv -p python3 .
```

I learn `.` is for 'current dir',
what syntax does '-' follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-p` is an option that allows you to specify which Python interpreter to use when creating the virtual environment.

You can find more info about `-p` and other options for `virtualenv` here: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/